# Android backstack with tasks and activities from different apps

Tags: android, android-activity, process, back-stack, android-task

I seem to find conflicting information with regards to the basic/default behavior of the backstack when dealing with tasks whose activities come from different apps. From my understanding so far:

- A **task** is a collection of activities where those activities could be entirely from 1 app or from a mix of multiple apps. Essentially (if I am understanding this correctly), a task is a "path/sequence of instantiated activities" -- regardless of what app these activities belong to.
- Each task has its own **backstack** of activities that maintains the order of these instantiated activities with the most recent activity on top
- Each **application** (e.g., GMail, Chrome, etc.) has its own dedicated Linux **process** with 1+ threads that have access to the code of that app's files. A process only executes the activities of its own app (not other apps).

**Question #1**: Assume activities A, B, and C belong to App<sub>1</sub> and activities X, Y, and Z belong to App<sub>2</sub>. If my Task has A->B on its backstack already and an implicit intent is sent to start Z, I am assuming that Z is then added to this Task's backstack. Correct?

**Follow-on Question #2**: When I am interacting with Z of my Task, the process running App<sub>2</sub> code is actually being executed (since it is the owner of Z's code/files). Then, if I press the Back button and navigate back to A, the process of App<sub>2</sub> is stopped and the process of App<sub>1</sub> is now executed (since it is the owner of A's code/files). Correct?